# Column matching in separate files

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have two files. I want to match coma separated values in the second column in the first part of `File1` to the values in the first column in `File2` and write in the `File2`. How do I do this in `awk`

File1

```
Column1    Column2
A          G1,G2
B          G4,G1
```

File2

```
G1
G2
```

Desired result

```
Column1    Column2
G1         A,B
G2         A
```

Comment: I do not have G4 in the second file so first awk '{ split($2,a,","); for (i in a) print $1, a[i]; }' file1.txt > intermediatefile.txt coma separated file are separated like this and then they second column of intermediate file has to match with the first column of file2 and get added as the last column with column separated

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
awk '
  NR==1 {
    print;
    next;
  }
  NR==FNR {
   split($2,a,","); 
   for(i in a) b[a[i]] = b[a[i]]==""? $1 : b[a[i]] "," $1;
   next;
  }
  {
    if ($1 in b) print $1 "\t" b[$1];
  }
  ' File1 File2
```

If you don't have / need the header line, you can simplify by dropping the first rule/action pair.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -nE ' chomp; 
   ($a,@b)= split(/[\t,]/,$_); 
   for(@b){ $aux{$_}.= ",$a" } 
   say "$_$aux{$_}" =~ s/,/\t/r  unless @b
   ' file1 file2
```

(ok, ok, I prefer @steeldriver version)